# Does Pixel have unit

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, pixel

Pixels, abbreviated as "px", are also a unit of measurement commonly used in graphic and web design, equivalent to roughly 1⁄96 inch (0.26 mm). This measurement is used to make sure a given element will display as the same size no matter what screen resolution views it.

THIS IS WRITTEN IN WIKIPEDIA IS IS CORRECT SO LIKE LENGTH PIXEL HAVE UNIT AND DIMENSIONS

Comment: What is the question? (I see no question mark). Also, what does graphic and web design have to do with image processing and neural networks? Please use the tag system in a way that the tags indicate what the question is about.

Answer (score 2):

"Pixel" both refers to a standardized unit and the individual parts of a screen. A pixel(px) is a unit, which makes sure that objects on a page will be the same size no matter the screen. As for the screen pixel, the size of a pixel on your screen depends on the resolution of your screen and the image.